# update a custom field with the value of another existing custom field

Tags: custom-field, save-post

I am trying to write a function to copy the value of an imported custom field (postalCode) to another custom field (wpcf-adres) when the post is saved or created. But i cannot get it to work, so there must be something not right in the code?
Thanks for any advice or solution given!

```
function sync_postalcode( $post_id ) {
 // GET Postal code FROM OTHER FIELD
     $postcode = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'postalCode', true);
 // UPDATE Postalcode IN adres FIELD
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-adres', $postcode );
 }

add_action( 'save_post', 'sync_postalcode' );
```

Comment: I'd try `$single = false`. So, what happens when you `$postcode = get_post_meta( 
 $post_id, 'postalCode' );`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that doesn't work also. or at least the field remains empty after updating the post

Comment: And you are sure about `wpcf-adres`? Not `wpcf_adres` or `wpcf_address` or something like that?

Comment: hi, yes the meta-key is stored in the database like: wpcf-adres